# Display a phone number based on the timezone

Tags: javascript, time, localization, timezone

I am trying to use JavaScript to display a phone number based on the timezone a user's PC is in, but I'm running into trouble. Below is the code that I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Offset Time</title>
</head>
<body onload ="timezone()">
<script type="text/javascript">
   var date = new Date();
   var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();  
   function timezone(){
   var Phone;
   var div=document.getElementById('date_dependent');
   if (offset = 240) {
        Phone = "1-877-219-8830";
    } else if (offset = 300) {
    Phone = "1-866-878-7814";
    } else {
    Phone = "1-877-868-8121";
   }
}
</script>
<div id="date_dependent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What output are you getting, what output are you expecting? Also, does this question actually involve Java?

Comment: How are phone numbers related to time zones?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your if statement.

```
if (offset = 240) {
```

should be

```
if (offset == 240) {
```

And

```
else if (offset = 300)
```

And your function definition should be

```
var timezone = function(){
```

here:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Offset Time</title>
</head>
<body onload ="timezone()">
<script type="text/javascript">
var date = new Date();
var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();  
var timezone = function(){
    var Phone;
    var div=document.getElementById('date_dependent');
    if (offset == 240) {
        Phone = "1-877-219-8830";
    } else if (offset == 300) {
        Phone = "1-866-878-7814";
    } else {
        Phone = "1-877-868-8121";
    }
}
</script>
<div id="date_dependent"></div>
```

Comment: [See It Run on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269777/2564301), courtesy of the new Snippet Runner. Hopefully to appear soon on the main site!

Answer (score 0):

In general, time zone detection by offset alone is not reliable.  This is because many time zones share the same offset, and time zones that use daylight saving time will use different offsets at different times of the year.  You can read more in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

However, there is a solution for your specific use case.  Assuming you are in the continental United States, and you don't care about customers from other countries, then you can test a specific point in time rather than the current time.  January 1st is a good test value to retrieve standard-time offsets, as it is not close to any daylight saving time transition.

```
var date = new Date(2014,0,1); // use Jan 1st, not the current date.
var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
var phone;
switch (offset) {
    case 300:
      phone = "The Eastern time zone phone number";
      break;
    case 240:
      phone = "The Central time zone phone number";
      break;
    default:
      phone = "The default phone number";
}
```

Note that if you wanted to distinguish Arizona from the rest of the country, as it does *not* use daylight saving time, you would need to test both a winter offset (Jan 1st) and a summer offset (Jul 1st).  I left this code out since it wasn't part of your original question.

Also, don't forget to actually use the value!

```
div.innerHTML = phone;
```

Comment: Now when i go to use the value in the HTML page how to i display it?

<h3 script src="phone.js"></h3> 

the java script works great but im not sure how to disply the phone variable

Comment: You shouldn't place a script src within an H3 tag.  The code you had already should work.  You just never assigned the value to the div tag.